# Set Terraform default interpreter for local-exec

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to override the default Terraform interpreter used in `local-exec` provisioners?

I am aware that you can set the interpreter via the `interpreter` argument, but I'm trying to avoid specifying this on every individual resource.

What I really want to do is override the "sensible defaults... chosen based on the system OS" for purposes of making the scripts cross-platform.  Specifically, I'd like to change the default via environment or command-line variable so I can use Cygwin Bash on Windows, for scripts that were originally made for Linux.

Does such a capability exist?

https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html

Comment: According to jen20's response on [terraform#7077](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7077), it doesn't seem possible at this time.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible today. Here is cross-platform sample code which you can use in any environment (hosted on my [gist](https://gist.github.com/aaronsteers/4b7a964d36cadd1dc092800106c0f0b1)).

First a snippet to detect the OS:

```
locals {
  # Directories start with "C:..." on Windows; All other OSs use "/" for root.
  is_windows = substr(pathexpand("~"), 0, 1) == "/" ? false : true
}
```

Then choose the interpreter and command based upon which OS is used:

```hcl
resource "null_resource" "cli_command" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    # Ensure windows always uses PowerShell, linux/mac use their default shell.
    interpreter = local.is_windows ? ["PowerShell", "-Command"] : []

    # TODO: Replace the below with the Windows and Linux command variants
    command     = local.is_windows ? "sleep 60" : "sleep 60"
  }
  triggers = {
    # TODO: Replace this psuedocode with one or more triggers that indicate (when changed)
    #       that the command should be re-executed.
    "test_a" = resource.my_resource.sample
  }
}
```

---

And finally, a simplified view without the extra comments and trigger:

```
resource "null_resource" "cli_command" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = local.is_windows ? ["PowerShell", "-Command"] : []
    command     = "sleep 60"
  }
}
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/396915/how-to-properly-format-terraform-hcl-code/396916#396916

Answer (score 0):

I used the sensible defaults approach because it works for me but you can do something similar utilizing the `interpreter` parameter as described by @aaronsteers. This is a script to generate an ssh key and apply proper permissions on Bash or Powershell, depending on where it is executed:

```
locals {
  is_windows = substr(pathexpand("~"), 0, 1) == "/" ? false : true
  key_file   = pathexpand("~/.ssh/${var.ssh_key_name}.pem")
}

locals {
  bash       = "chmod 400 ${local.key_file}"
  powershell = "icacls ${local.key_file} /inheritancelevel:r /grant:r ${var.os_username}:R"
}

resource "tls_private_key" "rsa_key" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "key_pair" {
  key_name   = var.ssh_key_name
  public_key = tls_private_key.rsa_key.public_key_openssh
}

resource "local_file" "my_key_file" {
  content     = tls_private_key.rsa_key.private_key_pem
  filename    = local.key_file

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = local.is_windows ? local.powershell : local.bash
  } 
}
```